# What is the polar set of $A= \{(1,\,1) \in \mathbb{R^2}\}$?

Tags: convex-analysis, solution-verification

The set A is in fact the single point $x = (1,\,1)$. Definition of polar set $A^* = \{ v \in \mathbb{R^n} : \langle u,\,v\rangle\, \leq 1 \,\,\forall u \in A\}$ (Note: $\langle u,\,v\rangle$ is the scalar product). In this case $n=2$. Let $u = (1,\,1)$ and $v=(x,\,y)$. So, $\langle u,\,v\rangle = x+y \leq 1$ or $y \leq 1-x$. The $A^\ast = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : y \leq 1 -x\}$ or we can write $A^\ast$ is the half-space $\langle x,\bar{n}\rangle \,\leq 1$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\bar{n}$ can be defined as $\bar{n} = (1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$.

I am new to Convex Analysis and would like to know if the above is correct. Perhaps, I missed something.

Comment: You should write $A^* = \{ (x,y) | x+y \le 1 \}$ or similar. This is a subset of the plane not the line.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion
$$
A^* = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} : x+y \leq 1 \}
$$
is a good way to describe the solution.

> $A^* = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : y \leq 1 -x\}$

This is wrong, since $A^*$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and not $\mathbb R$.

> or we can write $A^*$ is the half-space $<x,\bar{n}> \,\leq 1$ where $x \in \mathbb{R^2}$ and $\bar{n}$ can be defined as $\bar{n} = (1/\sqrt(2), 1/\sqrt(2))$.

This is also wrong, because you changed the left-hand side by multiplying with
$1/\sqrt{2}$, but not the right-hand side.
It would be better to use $\bar{n}=(1,1)$.

Comment: Yes I made typographical errors but many thanks for the comments especially for the definition of $\bar{n} =(1,1)$.